# Meaning of # in rsyslog.conf

Tags: syslog, rsyslog

I want to ask what means the `#` sign before `auth, authpriv.*` in `rsyslog.conf` in Debian, because `auth.log` file does not exist on my computer. Also, I have  this line: `#disable auth.log`.
Here's how it looks:

```
#disable auth.log
#auth,authpriv.*              /var/log/auth.log
#*.*;auth,authpriv.none      -/var/log/syslog
```

Comment: hashmark (`#`) almost always means comment at the beginning of line, and it's not interpreted.

Comment: So, is it normal this lines to be commented by default, because I have changed nothing in rsyslog.conf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [indicated](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/323391/auth-log-in-debian#comment568772_323391) by [Ipor Sircer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/182562/ipor-sircer), lines (or portions thereof) starting with `#` are often comments. This is the case in `rsyslog.conf` too, as documented in the [manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/rsyslog.conf.5.html#BASIC_STRUCTURE):

> Lines  starting  with  a  hash mark ('#') and empty lines are ignored.

In the example you give, the setup disables `auth.log`, but the lines are left as commented examples, presumably so that it's easy to enable it if desired.

Comment: So, is it normal this lines to be commented by default, because I have changed nothing in rsyslog.conf. Because I needed auth.log file to check some logs and this file is missing

Comment: No, it's not normal; the [default in Debian](https://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/collab-maint/rsyslog.git/tree/debian/rsyslog.conf) enables `auth.log` (at least as far back as March 2008).